# Can I make an asynchoronous method in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, methods, async-await

I have started learning about async in python. But in examples, I only see people use async keyword in functions. I wonder if I can use it with methods?

Here is what I tried:

```
import asyncio

class asyncClass:
    async def asyncMethod(self):
        print("Starting")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Ending!")
class1 = asyncClass()
class1.asyncMethod()
```

But I got this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'asyncClass.asyncMethod' was never awaited
  class1.asyncMethod()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I haven't figured out why this error happened because I already put `await` keyword into the method.

Comment: It's not complaining about the insides, but rather the usage. If you use something like `await class1.asyncMethod()` (in another async function) then there won't be a such a warning. But in any case, the program needs to have `asyncio.run(...)` somewhere to start async operations without a warning, as an answer below shows.

Comment: You would have gotten the exact same result if you did this with a regular async function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [asyncio.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) to execute the method: `asyncio.run(class1.asyncMethod())`